# HP UFT: Finding the windows of the application under test

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

My objective is to capture the mouse and keyboard events that UFT generates in the application-under-test (AUT), for use in a third-party application. Ideally, the solution should work with existing tests, or need just minimal changes.

Using [Windows hooking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the AUT would work, but this requires enumerating the AUT's window handles. Is there a generic way to get those?

The simplest solution would be doing this for objects in the test:

```
Set obj = Dialog("Login")
Print "HWND of the login dialog: " & Hex(obj.GetROProperty("hwnd"))
```

The obvious downside is manually coding this for each of the objects in each of the tests.

I tried enumerating the window and dialog objects, but it turns out UFT enumerates every window whether it belongs to the AUT or not:

```
Set desc = Description.Create  
Set objChildren = Desktop.ChildObjects(desc) 
' The following counts every open window on the desktop
Print "Objects under Desktop: " & objChildren.Count
```

Surprisingly, the test's object repositories turned up empty:

```
' The following line outputs zero
Print "Repository Count:" & RepositoriesCollection.Count
```

Querying individual actions' repositories also turned up no results:

```
Dim qtApp,qtRepositories, actName
actName=Environment.Value("ActionName")
Set qtApp = GetObject("", "QuickTest.Application") 'also tried with CreateObject
Set qtRepositories = qtApp.Test.Actions(actName).ObjectRepositories
' The following line outputs zero
Print "Action name: " & actName & " Repository count: " & qtRepositories.Count
```

There is still the option to use ObjectRepositoryUtil, but for that you need a repository path. As far as I can tell, the small test I have created based on the "Flight GUI" sample application, does not even contain a .tsr file which holds the object repository.

So is there another way in UFT to get the windows in the application under test?

Comment: It surely would help if you read the qtp user´s guide first. For example, creating an empty description with Description.Create and feeding that to Desktop.ChildObjects indeed returns all GUI objects matching the description -- that means in this case: all. You´d have to add properties to the description to make the description unique. But then, you would not need to call ChildObjects at all. See dox!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows to access all windows then loop it through with condition like window title match your application title. It's working find for me .